# transitive verb + to + verb

Tags: grammar

I sought to learn more./I managed to get help./I hope to win./I can afford to rent the car.

Are the verbs after 'to' also verbs? Should we see these verbs as secondary verbs? I want to know exactly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [t.v.+to+v pattern](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/527724/t-v-tov-pattern)

Comment: No, I need an exact explanation.

Comment: You need to modify your original question, rather than asking a duplicate one.